# Need help about this jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works perfectly but I need it to work when I open my browser. Also when I resize my browser to have mobile menu both functions work hover and toggle.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth < 1024) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
        $(".sub-menu").css("display", "block");
      }, function() {
        $(".sub-menu").css("display", "none");
      });
    });
  } else if (windowWidth > 1024) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This code should run when you resize your browser. What exactly isn't working and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

My best approach will be replacing the code with:

```
var reszFn = function(event) {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth < 1024) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
        $(".sub-menu").css("display", "block");
      }, function() {
        $(".sub-menu").css("display", "none");
      });
    });
  } else if (windowWidth > 1024) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle();
      });
    });
  }
};
$(document).on('ready', reszFn);
$(window).on('resize', reszFn);
```

Comment: Thanks but, when i resize my browser has both hover and toggle and when i m under 1024px width i want only toggle function.

Comment: @ViktorPetkovski You should not use `docReady` code inside, as it will never get executed as doc has already become ready. You need to consider using `.off().on()`. Just remove the `docReady` lines.

Comment: I remove docReady lines but now but is the same. Can you re edit the code please because i m stuck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the resize function

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth < 1024) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
        $(".sub-menu").css("display", "block");
      }, function() {
        $(".sub-menu").css("display", "none");
      });
    });
  } else if (windowWidth > 1024) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle();
      });
    });
  }
}).resize();
```